# How to relaunch a Spark executor after it crashes (in YARN client mode)?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

Is it possible to relaunch a Spark executor after it crashes? I understand that the failed tasks are re-run in the existing working Spark executors, but I hope there is a way to relaunch the crashed Spark executor.

I am running pyspark 1.6 on YARN, in client mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is not possible. Spark takes care of it and when an executor dies, it will request a new one the next time it asks for "resource containers" for executors.

If the executor was close to the data to process Spark will request for a new executor given locality preferences of the task(s) and chances are that the host where the executor has died will be used again to run the new one.

An executor is a JVM process that spawns threads for tasks and honestly does not do much. If you're concerned with the data blocks you should consider using Spark's external shuffle service.

Consider reading the document [Job Scheduling](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html) in the official documentation.

Comment: Sometimes all my Spark executors crashed and Spark just hanged. Is there a way to get out of the hanged state by exiting or raising an exception ?

Comment: Interesting. Never heard/seen it before. I'd appreciate seeing logs from a situation like this.

Comment: Ok, I will create another question discussion about it, thank you.